# why cant i see a like button on anyones page?

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I have a business facebook page, when I look at anyone elses page there is no like button, can anyone tell me why please?

Comment: You can get help from Facebook for user / account / site problems at https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012 - this is not the correct forum for those questions (see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  for more information)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are logged in as a Facebook user and not as the business page. A business page is just that, a page, not a user, but you can log in as the page to do posts and manage things on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it figured out! If you are logged into Facebook as your "page" you will not see the like button. You need to be using Facebook as your main (personal) profile. Go to your page, then click the "Edit Page" drop down at the top and select your main account "Use Facebook as ..." then it should display the like button. It worked for me! If it doesn't work at this point, try logging out and logging back in again. Good luck! :)